# How to fix JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, actions-on-google

[image][image]**I am working with the google actions console. Here I have a webhook, see the code below. Now when I run this I get the following error:**

*FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory*

```
const {
conversation,
Simple,
Canvas,
Card,
Link,
Suggestion,
Image,
} = require('@assistant/conversation');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');    
const app = conversation();

const categories = {
    nhgooi: {
        antwoorden: [
        'Ze willen dat pedojager onmiddelijk stoppen.',
        'Ze willen dat pedojagers zo doorgaan.',
        'Ze willen dat pedojagers pedofielen nog harder aanpakken.',
        'Ze willen dat pedojagers pedofielen blijven zoeken maar ze minder hard aanpakken.',
        ],
        vraag: [
            "Wat wilt de politie dat pedojagers doen?"
        ],
        image: {
        url: "https://storage.googleapis.com/gweb-uniblog-publish-prod/images/" +
            "Search_GSA.2e16d0ba.fill-300x300.png",
        alt: 'Google app logo',
        },
    },
    };


function randomarray(i_array, antwoorden, category){ //make an array with items in random order
    while (i_array.length > 0){
    i = Math.floor(Math.random() * i_array.length);
    var index = i - 1;
    antwoorden.push(categories[category].antwoorden[index]);
    delete i_array[index];
    }
    return antwoorden;
}

app.handle('NieuwsQuiz_Vragen', (conv) => {
    var antwoorden = [];
    var i_array = [0, 1, 2, 3];
    const category = conv.scene.slots.vraag_categorie.value; //gekozen categorie (regio)
    const vraag = categories[category].vraag[0];
    const antwoorden_shuffled = randomarray(i_array, antwoorden, category);
    const antwoorden_string = antwoorden_shuffled.toString();
    const image = categories[category].image[0];

    const prefix = `Jij hebt gekozen voor vragen uit ${category}, laten we snel beginnen!`;
    conv.add(prefix);
    const supportsRichResponse = conv.device.capabilities.includes("RICH_RESPONSE");
    if (supportsRichResponse) {
        conv.add(new Card({
        title: vraag,
        subtitle: antwoorden_string,
        image: new Image(image),
        button: new Link({
            name: 'Learn more',
            open: {
            url: 'https://www.google.com/about/'
            }
        })
        }));
    }
    // conv.add(new Simple({
    //     speech: `${prefix} ${vraag}`,
    //     text: vraag,
    // }));

    // for( let i=0 ; i <= antwoorden.length ; i++ ) {
    //     conv.add(new Suggestion({title: antwoorden[i]})); 
    // }
    //conv.add(new Suggestion({title: 'Quit'}));
});

exports.ActionsOnGoogleFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

**Does anyone know how to fix this? I have looked into other questions around this problem on Stack but all those solutions were to use in the terminal and not in a webhook.**

Comment: Try increases the memory limit with the flag --max_old_space_size.

Comment: https://github.com/endel/increase-memory-limit/issues/19

Comment: @kg99 thanks! I have added it to my code but it gives 2 errors:

Comment: - unexpected NODE OPTIONS

Comment: - bad assignment //(for the = sign)

Comment: I have added it like this: export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096

Comment: And also tried adding this: increase-memory-limit
===

Comment: Which node version are you using? That only works from node v8.0 . try node --max_old_space_size=4096 script.js.

Comment: Also you dont add it to your code. You add it to your environment so that node can pick it up. i.e execute export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=2048 on your terminal.

Comment: Alright, thank you @kg99! I am working with node v10 but I am working in the actions on google console > see image. Excecuting it in the terminal does not work for that right? Should I put it in package.josn?

Comment: Okay add --max_old_space_size=4096 where your call node. i.e node --max_old_space_size=4096 script.js.

Comment: @kg99 great! like this? See new picture

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224980/discussion-between-kg99-and-emilie-van-eps).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An OOM exception generally should not happen with your code as the default memory allocation is 256MB or 512MB, which is far more than you should need. This led me to believe you have a memory leak in your code.

Looking through, it seems to me that `randomarray` is doing it as you're doing array manipulations in a while loop, both of which can be potentially endless if you're not careful.

I've copied your randomarray function below:

```js
// make an array with items in random order
function randomarray(i_array, antwoorden, category){
    while (i_array.length > 0){
      i = Math.floor(Math.random() * i_array.length);
      var index = i - 1;
      antwoorden.push(categories[category].antwoorden[index]);
      delete i_array[index];
    }
    return antwoorden;
}
```

Based on your comment, I believe what you want is an array shuffle function.
It is used here:

```js
var antwoorden = [];
var i_array = [0, 1, 2, 3];
const category = conv.scene.slots.vraag_categorie.value; //gekozen categorie (regio)
const vraag = categories[category].vraag[0];
const antwoorden_shuffled = randomarray(i_array, antwoorden, category);
```

If I reproduce this function myself and add a few lines to observe what happens, I get this:

```
i_array: [,1,2,3] (Length 4)
i_array: [,,2,3] (Length 4)
i_array: [,,,3] (Length 4)
i_array: [,,,3] (Length 4)
i_array: [,,,3] (Length 4)
...
```

This seems to loop indefinitely, adding in one of your responses to the array each time. Over some time the array is going to become too large and crash.

Why does this happen? There seem to be a few mistakes in your implementation.

1. You have an `index` variable which is set to `i - 1`. This is incorrect as the algorithm `Math.floor(Math.random() * i_array.length)` will correctly return a valid index each time. Your implementation of `index` will always miss the last element in the array, causing the loop to continue forever.
2. The `delete` command will remove the value in a specific index but it will not change the array length. Rather, your array will have a value of `[empty, empty, empty, empty]`, an array that still has a length of 4. While you're computing until the length is 0, this loop will never end. Using the `splice` method will remove the element from the array *and* reduce the array length.

```js
function randomarray(i_array, antwoorden, category){
    while (i_array.length > 0) {
      i = Math.floor(Math.random() * i_array.length);
      antwoorden.push(categories[category].antwoorden[i]);
      i_array.splice(i, 1)
    }
    return antwoorden;
}
```

You can make these fixes or alternately consider using an off-the-shelf [npm module to shuffle arrays](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shuffle-array).